# removing words from a list after splitting the words :Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
List = ['iamcool', 'Noyouarenot'] 
stopwords=['iamcool']
```

What I want to do is to remove stowprds from my list. I am trying to acheive this with following script

```
query1=List.split()
resultwords  = [word for word in query1 if word not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
return result
```

So my result should be

```
result =['Noyouarenot']
```

I am receiving an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

which is right also, what small thing I am missing, please help. I appreciate every help.

Comment: `if 'iamcool' in List: List.remove('iamcool')`

Comment: Just remove that step and have `[word for word in List if word not in stopwords]`

Comment: You can't split a list, as Python is telling you.  Drop the `split()` part and just move forward as @roganjosh mentioned.

Comment: Also, `result = ' '.join(resultwords)` will return a string, not a list--have you referenced any Python documentation or tutorials for this code you're writing?

Comment: Thanks roganjosh- that was really helpful

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension with a condition checking for membership in `stopwords`.

```
print [item for item in List if item not in stopwords]
```

or `filter`

```
print filter(lambda item: item not in stopwords, List)
```

or `set` operations, you can refer to my answer on speed differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38977964/6320655).

```
print list(set(List) - set(stopwords))
```

**Output ->** `['Noyouarenot']`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the snippet fixing your error:

```
lst = ['iamcool', 'Noyouarenot']
stopwords = ['iamcool']

resultwords = [word for word in lst if word not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
print result
```

Another possible solution assuming your input list and stopwords list don't care about order and duplicates:

```
print " ".join(list(set(lst)-set(stopwords)))
```